# Youtube video upload fails in php after first chunk is sent

Tags: php, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am using Youtube API v3.0(php) to upload video to Youtube. Every time I run the script there's an error

> *An client error occurred: Failed to start the resumable upload.*

I placed some checkpoints and found out there's a problem in uploading the video in chunks.

```
while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
            $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
            $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
        }
```

I am using a video of size 10.8MB for uploading. Hence the above loop should run for 11 times but it throws an error on the first time and hence the client error message.

Code:

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()){
    try{
        // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
        $videoPath = 'test.mp4';

        // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
        // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
        // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
        // video category.
        $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
        $snippet->setTitle($title);
        $snippet->setDescription($description);
        $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

        // Numeric video category. See
        // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
        $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

        // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
        // "private" and "unlisted".
        $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
        $status->privacyStatus = "private";

        // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
        $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
        $video->setSnippet($snippet);
        $video->setStatus($status);

        // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
        // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
        // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
        $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
        // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
        $client->setDefer(true);

        // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
        $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

        // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
        $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
            $client,
            $insertRequest,
            'video/*',
            null,
            true,
            $chunkSizeBytes
        );
        $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));

        // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
        $status = false;
        $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");

        while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
            $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
            $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
        }

        fclose($handle);

        // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
        $client->setDefer(false);

        $htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $status['snippet']['title'], $status['id']);

        $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    }
}
```

Comment: With the error, you should also be able to see what the HTTP code was ... 400, 401, 403, etc. Can you retrieve that? Often this particular error message is indicative of using the wrong authorization method; have you checked your oAuth2 flow to make sure it's working properly, and that you're getting the user's access token?

Comment: It does not return any error code, I did try to catch the error code and it was returning 0. Regarding the authorization method, the same system works in localhost but when I try it on server it gives the error: Failed to start resumable upload. I did check whether I'm getting the access code/token.

Comment: I solved this problem by running the script independently. It seems like there was another process running in parallel with the upload script. And might be due to security issues, Youtube Api doesn't allows that. Now it works good for me.